# ExtJS Message Box YESNO to NOYES?

Tags: extjs

Is there any way to swap the buttons from YESNO to NOYES in an confirmation message box without touching the core ext-all.js library? Basically, if there is an confirmation like "Are you sure you want to cancel?", then the NO button should be in the left and YES button should be in the right.

Comment: I have done a workaround but looking for correct way of doing it `showConfirm: function (msgTxt, fn) {
                var me = this;
                me.show({
                    title: 'TCA',
                    msg: msgTxt,
                    closable: false,
                    //buttons:Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
                    buttonText: { no: 'No', cancel: 'Yes' },
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.QUESTION,
                    fn: fn
                }); `

Comment: I think that could be quite a confusing UI to provide a confirmation where no is on the left

Comment: I agree but this is a specific requirement to interchange the buttons. So, I have left with no options other than finding a solution for it.

Comment: Yeah if you 'have to' I guess renaming the buttons would be fine, either that, or manually define them by defining the 'buttons' collection: 
buttons: [
  { text: 'Button 1' }
]